# apt upgrade, failed to fetch package. Forbidden

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

I have read the other posts that are similar to my problem, but their solutions did not help.

This is the error: E: Failed to fetch https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/pool/main/g/gdal/python3-gdal_3.0.4+dfsg-1+b1_amd64.deb  Redirection from https to 'http://mirrors.mit.edu/parrot/pool/main/g/gdal/python3-gdal_3.0.4+dfsg-1+b1_amd64.deb' is forbidden [IP: 104.27.130.193 443]

In my browser both URLs will download the .deb, so it's not like it IS forbidden or is a dead link so,, what gives? How can I fix this? Can I manually download the .deb and place it where it would go usually and fix it that way?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. My time was off. I changed the time to be accurate with 
`date -s "correct time nstuff here"`
after fixing my time I was able to download all packages.